# Memory Game - Feeding an image array to a grid button matrix

Tags: java, arrays, swing, netbeans

I have my buttons created from my Design View in Netbeans (of type JToggleButton)

ex. btn00, btn01 ...

I have one matrix for my grid (Memory game style):

int matriz[][] = new int [4][6];

I have another matrix for where my images are (of type ImageIcon) and I use this method to go through it:

```
public ImageIcon[] ArrayIconos()
{
    ImageIcon Disney[] = new ImageIcon[25];

    for (int n=0; n<25; n++)
    {
        Disney[n] = new ImageIcon("Disney"+(n+1)+".png");
        System.out.println(Disney[n]);
    }

    return Disney;

}
```

How could I feed my image matrix (Disney) into my matrix called matriz so I can load the images to the buttons?

Thanks for your help in advanced. Please let me know if my explanation is not clear enough.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking, `matriz` is array of `int`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What values are in `matriz`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a memory game doesn't need to know that the cells are arranged in a rectangular matrix; it only cares if two cells have matching images. This [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons) uses two instances of `List<GameButton>`

- `buttons` holds all of the memory cells.
- `selected` records the current selection(s).