# Memory Game fails

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, action

I am trying to make a simple memory game. but I don't know how to set up actionPerformed where when 1 button is pressed, then the program waits for another click and checks if the buttons are the same?
Right now all the code does it create random spots for but[x](set up in other method) and when the button is pressed the button changes to the image to correct image

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {

    for(int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
        if(a.getSource() == but[x]) {
            but[x].setIcon(imageicon[x / 2]); //Another method creates the imageicons

        } 

        frame.repaint();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No need to call `repaint()` if all you're doing is changing a JLabel or JButton's Icon.
2. You will need your ActionListener to contain a variable, perhaps an Icon variable, that holds the value of the last button's Icon, and let's call it `lastIcon`. It will initially hold a value of `null`.
3. When the first button is pressed, its icon is displayed, it checks the value of lastIcon. If it is null, it knows that this is the first button, and the lastIcon variable is assigned its icon's value.
4. When the 2nd button is pressed, it displays its icon, checks it against the last one. If equal, it keeps both buttons displayed. If not equal, it starts a Swing Timer that resets the Icons back to default. Either way, it sets the lastIcon to null.
5. Note that you do *not* want to check if one button == another button. You want to either compare their Icons, or else have a separate model class that is distinct from your view, and check if the two buttons are equivalent in your model.

Comment: How would you set up the buttons, one with but[x] and then one with but[x+1]?

Comment: @ImGone98: please provide context for your question. Your comment above is written as if I understand your entire program, and truth is, I don't. I've only seen one little method of it, so I can't.

Comment: @ImGone98: For reference, many of these valuable guidelines are seen in the example cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10326636/230513).